# Problems with POSTing to FHIR from Databricks

Tags: json, rest, postman, hl7-fhir

I am trying to insert data into FHIR from Databricks. I have dynamically generated my HL7 code, which when I test it directly in Postman I manage to POST without problems, but when I do it from Databricks I get the following error:

```
{"resourceType":"OperationOutcome","id":"21e75c73f1d000f2de7de02","meta":{"lastUpdated":"2022-08-23T18:30:17.9799097+00:00"},"issue":[{"severity":"error","code":"invalid","diagnostics":"Error occurred when parsing model: 'Unable to translate bytes [D3] at index 856 from specified code page to Unicode.'."}]}

Error Code: 400
```

It is worth mentioning that I have done other tests from Databricks with JSON HL7 code on hard without problems, but when I make it dynamic, even though it runs correctly in Postman, I get the above error...

My dynamic JSON HL7 statement is as follows:

```
data = """
{
"resourceType" : "Patient",
"identifier" : [{ 
        "use" : "official", 
        "type" : { 
            "coding": [
            {
                "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
                "code": "NNcol"
            }, {
                "system": "https://registraduria.gov.co/identificaciones",
                "code": "CC",
                "display": "Cedula de Ciudadania"
            }
        ] }, 
        "value" : """ +    str(v_id_paciente)   + """
},
{ 
    "use" : "usual", 
    "type" : { 
        "coding": [
        {
            "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
            "code": "MR",
            "display": "Medical record number"    
        }
    ] }, 
    "value" :  """  + str(v_registro_medico) + """
}
],
"active": true,
"telecom": [
    {
        "system": "phone",
        "value": """ + str(v_telefono) + """,
        "use": "mobile"
    }
],
"name": [
    {
        "use": "official",
        "family": """ + str(v_nombre) + """
    }
],
"gender": """ + str(v_sexo) + """,
"birthDate": """ + str(v_fecha_nac) + """,
"address" : [
    {
        "text" : """ + str(v_dire_part) + """ ,
        "city": """ + str(v_region) + """
    }
]
}"""
```

The output is as follows and runs smoothly in Postman:

```
{
"resourceType" : "Patient",
"identifier" : [{ 
        "use" : "official", 
        "type" : { 
            "coding": [
            {
                "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
                "code": "NNcol"
            }, {
                "system": "https://registraduria.gov.co/identificaciones",
                "code": "CC",
                "display": "Cedula de Ciudadania"
            }
        ] }, 
        "value" : "17.003.627-K"
},
{ 
    "use" : "usual", 
    "type" : { 
        "coding": [
        {
            "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
            "code": "MR",
            "display": "Medical record number"    
        }
    ] }, 
    "value" :  0.1449191882121713
}
],
"active": true,
"telecom": [
    {
        "system": "phone",
        "value": 9217432,
        "use": "mobile"
    }
],
"name": [
    {
        "use": "official",
        "family": "Patrick Mess"
    }
],
"gender": "male",
"birthDate": "1988-08-01",
"address" : [
    {
        "text" : "AV. CONCÓN 0132, VALPARAÍSO" ,
        "city": "VALPARAÍSO"
    }
]
}
```

Thank you for your time, I look forward to hearing from you.

Thank you very much.

Regards

---

SOLUTION:

Thanks you very much for you help in my post.

Finally, I have been able to find the problem; From Databricks you have to be careful with the encoding that the message is sent (it is not the same as that of Postman), I managed to notice because I modified all the special characters of the post message. Thus giving to identify the problem.

Below I share some codes in case someone needs them to solve the task.

```
vv_region = re.sub(
        r"([^n\u0300-\u036f]|n(?!\u0303(?![\u0300-\u036f])))[\u0300-\u036f]+", r"\1", 
        normalize( "NFD", vv_region), 0, re.I
    )

# -> NFC
N_v_region = normalize( 'NFC', vv_region)

print(N_v_region)
```

Regards!

Comment: I would consider adding FHIR-Validation (at the LEAST in your developer cycles) to your pre-sending.    https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir/tree/master/hapi-fhir-base/src/main/java/ca/uhn/fhir/validation     I actually created a MyRealFhirValidator and a MyEmptyFhirValidator (that implements the same interface)... so I can swap in and out the functionality with IoC/DI.        I know that's a little trickier with DataBricks.      But I never "assume" my fhir-payload is all-good.  I make sure before I pay the price.

Comment: private Collection<String> internalValidateObject(final IBaseResource ibr) {

        Collection<String> returnItems = new ArrayList<>();

        ValidationResult result = validator.validateWithResult(ibr); /* where validator is injected ca.uhn.fhir.validation.FhirValidator; */

        // The result object now contains the validation results
        for (SingleValidationMessage next : result.getMessages()) {
            returnItems.add(next.getSeverity() + " - " + next.getLocationString() + " - " + next.getMessage());
        }

        return returnItems;
    }

Comment: import ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext;
import ca.uhn.fhir.validation.FhirValidator;
import ca.uhn.fhir.validation.SingleValidationMessage;
import ca.uhn.fhir.validation.ValidationResult;
import org.hl7.fhir.instance.model.api.IBaseResource;